# How to get Processor Id from win32 processor

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, wmi

```
string strProcessorId = string.Empty;
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_processor");
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

foreach (ManagementObject info in search.Get())
{
    strProcessorId = info["processorId"].ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(strProcessorId);
Console.ReadLine();
```

it gives error for line

```
strProcessorId = info["processorId"].ToString();
```

error is: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

how to remove this error

Comment: I'm currently working on an app that depends on the WMI ProcessorID like OP for some crypto work. I'm getting the exact same issue as them. It seems like some platforms cannot be depended upon to provide a ProcessorID, so you need to plan for it not being available.

Answer (score 1):

WMI property names are probably case-sensitive. Try:

```
strProcessorId = info["ProcessorId"].ToString();
```

It might also help to properly capitalize the name of the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373.aspx) class:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Processor");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    string strProcessorId = string.Empty;
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_processor");
    ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

    foreach (ManagementObject info in search.Get())
    {
        strProcessorId = info["ProcessorID"].ToString();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(strProcessorId);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

think it was just the capital missing that meant a null was being returned